# Explode collection and save some fields.

Tags: c#, linq, collections

I have the following class:

```
class Item
{
    public string[] field1;
    public int field2;
}
```

Well i have collection of items. How can i convert these collection to

```
class Item
{
    public string field1;
    public int field2;
}
```

I mean something like `Items.SelectMany(x => x.field1)` but i need to save `filed2` value for each element of my collection.

example

```
field1:{"asd","asdf","fscsd"}
field2:123

->

field1:{"asd"}
field2:123

field1:{"asdf"}
field2:123

field1:{"fscsd"}
field2:123
```

Comment: @svick i can do it with loop but it is not elegant solution. So...that's why i asked community

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
var res = Items.SelectMany(x => x.field1.Select(s => new {field1=s, x.field2}));
```

You will get back an enumerable of *anonymous objects*, each with two fields - `field1` and `field2`.

Answer (score 1):

I think this serves its purpose:

First, change your classes to this: (both a different name)

```
class Items
{
    public string[] field1;
    public int field2;
}

class Item
{
    public string field1;
    public int field2;
}
```

then, this function will divide your first class into two (or more) other classes

```
public Item[] splitItems(Items item)
{
    Item[] items = new Item[item.field1.length];
    for(int i=0;i<item.field1.length;i++)
    {
        items[i].field1 = item.field1[i];
        items[i].field2 = item.field2;
    }
    return items;
}

Items mainItem = new Items();
mainItem.field1 = {"asd","asdf","fscsd"};
mainItem.field2 = 123;

Item[] tempItems = splitItems(mainItem);
```

Now you're supposed to see that:

tempItems[0].field1 = "asd";
tempItems[1].field1 = "asdf";
tempItems[2].field1 = "fscsd";

and all their field2's will equal 123